# data structure : Implementation of Queue in c++ using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, queue

i tried to implement a c++ queue list using pointers but i got some error :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node{
int age;
string firstname;
string lastname;
node *next;
};
typedef node*pqueue;
struct queue{
pqueue head;
pqueue tail;
};
```

initialize the queue

```
void init(queue &q){
    (q->head) = (q->tail)=NULL;
}
```

---

insert a data from tail

```
void insert(queue &q,int x,string fn,string ln){
    if((q->head=0)&&(q->tail=0)){
        q->head=new node;
        (q->head)->age=x;
        (q->head)->firstname=fn;
        (q->head)->lastname=ln;
        q->tail=q->head;
    }else{
        pqueue temp = new node;
        temp->age=x;
        temp->firstname=fn;
        temp->lastname=ln;
        temp->next=q->tail;
        q->tail=temp;
    }

}
```

---

remove or pop function

```
void remove(queue &q){
if((q->head=0)&&(q->tail=0))
    cout<<"the queue is empty nothing to remove .....!"<<endl;
else{
    pqueue temp = q->head;
    q->head=(q->head)->next;
    delete q->head;
}}
void forward(queue &q){
 pqueue temp =q->head;
while(temp != q->tail)
    {
    cout<<"age          :"<<temp->age<<endl;
    cout<<"first name   :"<<temp->firstname<<endl;
    cout<<"last  name   :"<<temp->lastname<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    temp=temp->next;
}
}
void backward(queue &q){
pqueue temp =q->head;
if(temp->next != q->tail)
    backward(temp->next);
    cout<<"age          :"<<temp->age<<endl;
    cout<<"first name   :"<<temp->firstname<<endl;
    cout<<"last  name   :"<<temp->lastname<<endl;
}
```

main code ......................

```
int main()
{
    queue q;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int choice = 0,age;
    cout<<"********************LIST-QUEUE IMPLEMENTATION********************"<<endl;
    while(choice!=6)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Choose an Option : \n 1.Initialization \n 2.Push \n 3.Pop \n 4.Traverse Forward \n 5.Traverse Backward \n 6.Quit \n ==> ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
        init(q);
        break;
        case 2:
        cout<<"enter the first name : ";
        cin>>firstname;
        cout<<"enter the last name  : ";
        cin>>lastname;
        cout<<"enter the age        : ";
        cin>>age;
        insert(q,age,firstname,lastname);
        break;
        case 3:
            remove(q);
        break;
        case 4:
            forward(q);
        break;
        case 5:
            backward(q);
        break;
        case 6:
        break;
        default:
            cout<<" Not available.......! check again ..... [1...6] : ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

one of problem i got is that 
**error base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'queue'**
it seems that i have this issue for every function 
please i need some help here .........

Comment: If you program in C++ please don't add the C language tags. Those are two very different languages.

Comment: You are passing queue by reference. So you should use q.head, q.tail instead of -> (pointer dereference)

Comment: Also, you seem to have forgotten the difference between assignment using `=` and comparison for equality with `==`.

Comment: Lastly, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then remember to always include the actual errors you get (copy-pasted in full and complete).

Comment: Don't set unused pointers to `NULL`, instead use `nullptr`.

Comment: it seems the problem was at q.head not q->tail